# A set of n vectors spans $\mathbb R^{n} $ if and only if the determinant of the matrix they form is nonzero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> A set of $n$ vectors spans $\mathbb R^{n}$ if and only if the determinant of the matrix they form is nonzero?

I get why it's true in one direction; that if the determinant of the matrix is nonzero, it spans $\mathbb R^ {n} $ -- because of the fact that if the determinant of a matrix A is 0, then A**x = b** has a unique solution for every **b**.

But if the determinant of the matrix is zero, it doesn't mean that there is *no* solution for every **b**, it just means that there isn't a *unique* solution for every **b**, correct? So couldn't there be an infinite amount of solutions for every **b**, or a unique solution for some values of **b** and an infinite amount for others, in which case the set of vectors would, in fact, span $\mathbb R^{n}$? Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong. I tried looking at a similar question on here, but the answers talked about basis, which isn't something my book covers until the next section.

Comment: No unique solution to $Ax=b$ for some particular $b$ $\implies$ nontrivial nullspace of $A$ $\implies$ no unique solution for *any* vector $b$

Comment: some vectors can be made infinitely many ways, others can't be made at all...

Comment: I'm not sure how you arrived at no unique solution for any vector b; I haven't learned about nontrivial nullspace...Also, even if I accept that that's true, couldn't there still be an infinite amount of solutions for every vector b?

Comment: You will have infinite amount of solutions for certain vectors for sure. But there are other vectors in that same $R^n$ (meaning for the same $n$) that you cannot make, and that it precisely because Det=0 .

Comment: If the determinant of a matrix A is 0, then you can't guarantee that Ax = b has unique solution for every b.

Comment: How do you know that there are some that you can't make? How does a 0 determinant imply that?

Comment: Consider the matrix A = $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and the vector b = $\begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: You say that you haven't covered bases yet in your course, but it would be useful instead to specify what you *do* have covered. This result can be approached from different directions, depending on what you have already studied. For instance: have you already defined a kernel? Have you computed the general solution of a linear system using free variables and pivots?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni kernel no, general solution using free variables yes, pivots no -- we've been solving matrices using gaussian elimination

Comment: @dagny I am confused - how can you have covered Gaussian elimination but not pivots? They are a central concept to understand elimination. Maybe you call them with a different name? How do you call the positions of the "steps" in the echelon form?

Comment: Well, I don't know, I'm assuming my book just chose not to refer to them by that name. The way my book does Gaussian elim is just by getting a leading one in a row, then eliminating the entries below it, then getting a leading one in the row below, etc.

Comment: @dagny Indeed, those leading ones are called *pivots* in the rest of the world. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to prove this.  Here's an algebraic approach:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix of determinant $0$.  Let $B$ be this matrix in row echelon form.  We can write $B = E_1E_2 \cdots E_nA$, where the $E_k$'s are [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) corresponding to the various row operations that put $A$ into row-echelon form.  Bearing in mind that determinant is multiplicative, we can take the determinant of both sides above to get:
$$\det(B) = \det(E_1E_2 \cdots E_nA) = \det(E_1)\det(E_2) \cdots \det(E_n)\det(A) = 0$$

$B$ is an upper triangular matrix, so [its determinant is given by the product of its diagonal entries](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Triangular_Matrix).  Since $\det(B) = 0$ and it is a square matrix in row echelon form, it is forced that at least one row of $B$ is a row of zeros.  This tells us that a nontrivial linear combination of rows of $A$ yields the zero vector.  Therefore, the $n$ row vectors of $A$ cannot be linearly independent $\implies$ they do not span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: "Therefore, the n row vectors of A cannot be linearly independent ⟹ they do not span Rn" I thought a set of linearly dependent vectors could still span Rn?

Comment: Sure @dagny, but it'd need to be more than $n$ of them.  If a set of $n$ dependent vectors spanned $\mathbb{R}^n$, then you could find a linearly independent subset of them that would *still* span $\mathbb{R}^n$.  But $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of dimension $n$, meaning the smallest possible spanning set of vectors for the space has $n$ elements.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense.

Comment: Okay, so using R^2 as an example, am I now correct in thinking that the only situations in which a set of vectors wouldn't span R^2 are if 1) all the vectors in the set lie in the same line, or 2) there are less than 2 vectors in the set? I didn't really have that understanding before...I'm only just getting used to concept of spanning. So that makes things a lot clearer. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: That's correct!  On the other hand, if you have two vectors that do not lie on the same line, they span all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have seen the general solution of a linear system using free variables. You have probably seen that to solve a linear system you should apply Gaussian elimination operations on the rows of the matrix $A$, and then repeat them on the entries of $b$ (or apply them to the matrix $[A\,\, b]$, which is effectively the same), producing respectively $R$ and $f$. The set of solutions of $Rx=f$ is the same as the set of solutions of $Ax=b$.

If a matrix is square and singular, then this procedure produces a zero row (or more) at the bottom of $R$ (this is how you have defined "singular", I guess?). There are some choices of the starting vector $b$ that produce a zero in the last position of $f$; for instance, $b=0$. There are some choices of $b$ that produce a nonzero in the last position of $f$; for instance, if no row exchanges are required for Gaussian elimination, you can take $b=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

These correspond, respectively, to a system with an infinite number of solutions and a system with no solutions (by the general solution algorithm). So we have proved that for each square singular $A$ there are choices of $b$ that produce an infinite number of solutions and some that produce no solutions.